# Masonry Center when colums are too large and leave a gap on the right

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry, centering, masonry

I am new to javascript.  I really only know html css and adding masonry to my new tumblr theme was a challenge I wanted to undergo and it is proving to be just that: a challenge.

my example page: [Example](http://hyungjun-idolanon.tumblr.com/)

You can see that if the columns cannot fill the whole page then a large gap will be on the right of the masonry grid.  What I want is to have that grid center according to the width of the window size if that gap exists.

I have tried hacking this with css using auto margins on .masonry and on .entry masonry-brick and no luck.

I figured this might be something fixed in javascript/jquery but I'm too new to it.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/6hsqxdt/vmwm2rb4g/infinitescrolling.js">
</script>
<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/6hsqxdt/QBym35odk/jquery.masonry.js"></script>

<script>
$(function(){
var $container = $('#posts');
$container.imagesLoaded(function(){
$container.masonry({
itemSelector: '.entry',
});
});
var container = document.querySelector('#container');
var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
  columnWidth: 250,
  itemSelector: '.entry'
});

$container.infinitescroll({
itemSelector : ".entry",
navSelector : "div.pagination",
nextSelector : ".pagination a#next",
loadingImg : "",
loadingText : "<em></em>",
bufferPx : 10000,
extraScrollPx: 12000,
},
// trigger Masonry as a callback
function( newElements ) {
  var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
// ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
$newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
$newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
$container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true );
});
}
);
});
</script>
```

Here is all of the code (the code was copy and pasted from a theme developer who was opening this for other developers).

Thanks in advance for anybody's help.